# Asignación de evento onClick usando reemplazo de texto

Tags: javascript, html, extensión-google-chrome

### Código

```js
/**
 * Arreglo de telefonos
 */
var telefonos = [
  "316 841 1233",
  "321 876 5432",
  "318 220 0880",
  "313 123 4567",
  "315 321 7654",
  "315 366 6666",
  "2874566",
  "2661588",
  "2662255",
  "3153274802",
  "2771521"
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Elementos */
  var body = document.body;
  var html = body.innerHTML;

  var htmlModificado;

  /* Buscamos cada telefono del arreglo */
  telefonos.forEach(function(telefono) {

    /* Creamos la etiqueta "phone" */
    var phone = crearPhone(telefono);

    htmlModificado = html.replace(telefono, phone.outerHTML);
    body.innerHTML = htmlModificado;

    html = body.innerHTML;

  });

});

function generarMensaje(elemento) {
  console.log("Enviando mensaje a " + elemento.innerHTML);
}

function crearPhone(telefono) {

  var phone = document.createElement("phone");

  phone.innerHTML = telefono;

  phone.setAttribute("class", "enlace");
  phone.onclick = function() {
    generarMensaje(this);
  }

  return phone;
}
```

```css
.enlace {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

.enlace:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido">
  <div>
    <div>316 841 1233</div>
    <div>321 876 5432</div>
    <div>318 220 0880</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>313 123 4567</a>
    <br>
    <a>315 321 7654</a>
    <br>
    <a>315 366 6666</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    2874566 - 2661588 - 2662255
  </div>
  <div>
    3153274802 - 2771521
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Contexto

Estoy trabajando en una extensión de Chrome, que se encargara de realizar ciertas modificaciones en el DOM de un sitio, buscando algunos textos y reemplazándolos por ciertas etiquetas personalizadas, que permitirán realizar algunas acciones en especifico.

Es decir, la extension hara esto:

1) Busca un texto donde este la palabra "amor"

```
<a>Hay amor en el aire.</a>
```

2) Agregara la etiqueta personalizada

```
<a>Hay <palabra onclick="buscar()">amor</palabra> en el aire.</a>
```

---

### Objetivo

En el ejemplo previamente expuesto, necesito hacer lo siguiente:

> Teniendo un sitio, con un listado de números en distintos niveles y dentro de distintas etiquetas dentro del DOM, me basare en un arreglo que contiene dichos números, y los buscare uno a uno los iré encerrando en una etiqueta personalizada llamada `<phone>`, permitiendole a cada uno de estos números tener una acción distinta al resto del texto alrededor.

---

## Problema

En esta seccion de mi codigo:

```
function crearPhone(telefono) {

  var phone = document.createElement("phone");

  phone.innerHTML = telefono;

  phone.setAttribute("class", "enlace");
  phone.onclick = function() {
    generarMensaje(this);
  }

  return phone;
}
```

Creo la función a la que le indicare el numero que vamos a encerrar en la etiqueta `<phone>`, asignando allí la clase, el evento `onclick`.

Si se ejecuta el codigo, todos los numeros de telefono han cambiado de color exitosamente, el problema ocurre en que ninguno de ellos ejecuta la funcion que se asigno durante el `onclick`:

```
  phone.onclick = function() {
    generarMensaje(this);
  }
```

Por lo tanto el código no imprime ningún mensaje ni ningún error en la consola.

---

### Nota

> Cabe aclarar que el problema lo debo **solucionar usando JavaScript puro**, no me sirve usar una librería como jQuery u otros, ya que en dicho entorno no puedo hacer uso de ella.

Comment: Lo que buscas hacer es la exención de skype?

Comment: Parecido, pero es para hacer busquedas de ciertas palabras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en `Phone.outerHTML`, puesto que no serializa los eventos en DOM, el hacer `phone.onclick = ...` afecta al elemento DOM mas no a su elemento HTML serializado.

## Solución

reemplaza `phone.onclick` con `phone.setAttribute('onclick',...)`

```
function crearPhone(telefono) 
{
  var phone = document.createElement("phone");
  phone.innerHTML = telefono;
  phone.setAttribute("class", "enlace");
  phone.setAttribute("onclick", 'generarMensaje(this)');
  return phone;
}
```

## Una mejor alternativa

Puesto que trabajas sobre elementos serializados, estos aún deben ser parseados por *DOM.parser*, ya sea directa o indirectamente con los sets de *innerHTML* / *outerHTML*. Lo mejor es editar directamente el *DOM* en lugar del html serializado.

```js
;(function(global, d)
{
"use strict"

  var telefonos = [
    "316 841 1233"
    ,"321 876 5432"
    ,"318 220 0880"
    ,"313 123 4567"
    ,"315 321 7654"
    ,"315 366 6666"
    ,"2874566"
    ,"2661588"
    ,"2662255"
    ,"3153274802"
    ,"2771521"
  ]
  
  function crearTelefono(telefono)
  {
    var p = d.createElement('phone')
    p.appendChild(d.createTextNode(telefono))
    p.classList.add('enlace')
    p.onclick = generarMensaje
    return p
  }
  
  function generarMensaje(elemento) {
    console.log("Enviando mensaje a " + elemento.target.firstChild.nodeValue);
  }
  
  function reemplazar_telefonos()
  {
    reemplazar_telefonos_aux(document.body);
  }
  
  function reemplazar_telefonos_aux(node)
  {
    for (var h of node.childNodes)
      {
        if (h.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
         {
           analizar_y_reemplazar(h)
         }
        else if (h.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE 
                 && h.nodeName != 'SCRIPT' 
                 && h.nodeName != 'STYLE'
                 && h.nodeName != 'PHONE')
         {
           reemplazar_telefonos_aux(h)
         } 
      }  
  }
  
  function analizar_y_reemplazar(tnode)
  {
    var s = tnode.nodeValue
    var p = tnode.parentNode, i
    
    for (var telefono of telefonos)
      {             
        while ((i = s.indexOf(telefono)) >= 0)
          {
            var a = s.slice(0, i)
            s = s.slice(i + telefono.length, s.length)
            if (a)
              { 
                p.insertBefore(d.createTextNode(a), tnode)  
              }
            p.insertBefore(crearTelefono(telefono), tnode)
          }
      }
      tnode.nodeValue = s 
  }
  
  global.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', reemplazar_telefonos, false)
  
}(window, document))
```

```css
.enlace {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

.enlace:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
  <div>
    <a>313 123 4567</a>
    <br>
    <h3> El numero es: 313 123 4567 </h3>
    <a>315 321 7654</a>
    <br>
    <a>315 366 6666</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <em> Texto con enfásis 2874566 </em> <br> <span style="color:red"> rojo 2661588 </span> - 2662255
    <ul>
      <li><span style="color:green"> verde 2874566 </span></li>
      <li><span style="color:cyan"> cyan 315 366 6666</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span style="color:pink"> Rosado 3153274802 - 2771521 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que hace el anterior código es analizar recursivamente todo el texto, a cualquier profundidad, reemplazar dicho texto por un elemento `phone` (*UnknownHTMLElement*) y finalmente hace el nodo un nodo dummy (vacío), la razón del nodo dummy es para simplificar el código